# ¿Cómo agregar un arreglo bidimensional a un arreglo en React usando el hook useState?

Tags: array, reactjs, array-bidimensional

Tengo la siguiente variable de estado, la cual es un arreglo bidimensional de 3x3

```
const [posiciones, setPosiciones] = useState([[null, null, null], [null, null, null], [null, null, null]]);
```

En la variable de estado historial se va a almacenar la variable posiciones, por lo tanto la variable historial sería un arreglo que tiene un conjunto de arreglos bidimiensionales.

```
const [historial, setHistorial] = useState([]);
```

Al momento de que el usuario da clic en un botón, se ejecuta la siguiente función, en la cual se cambia el valor de la variable posiciones de acuerdo al lugar en donde dió clic el usuario, y a su vez, se cambia el valor de la variable historial, en la cual se almacena el arreglo bidimensional.

```
const cambiarSimbolo = posicion =>
{
    let posicionesAux = posiciones;

    if(posicion <= 3)
        posicionesAux[0][posicion - 1] = simbolo;
    else if(posicion <= 6)
        posicionesAux[1][posicion - 4] = simbolo;
    else
        posicionesAux[2][posicion - 7] = simbolo;

    setPosiciones(posicionesAux);
    setHistorial([...historial, posicionesAux]);
    setIntento(intento + 1);
    setSimbolo(simbolo === "X" ? "O" : "X");
}
```

La siguiente función es la encargada de mostrar lo que contiene la variable historial en determinada posición, el error esta en la variable historial, ya que en cada posición tiene el ultimo valor del arreglo bidimensional, ósea de la variable posición.

```
const verHistorial = indice =>
{
    console.log(historial[indice - 1]);
}
```

Por ejemplo, si se cambia el valor de la variable historial por primera vez y luego se intenta ver el contenido del arreglo en la posicion 0, este es el resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al momento de volver a agregar un elemento a la variable historial, se sustituye el valor en la posición 0 por el nuevo valor de posición, por lo tanto, en cada posicion de la variable historial se repite el valor de la variable posición.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, ¿Qué tendría que hacer para evitar que en cada posición de la variable historial no se repita el mismo arreglo bidimensional?

Comment: ¿Tienes feedback? ¿lograste avanzar? saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este momento, se esta usando la misma referencia en memoria del `array` `posiciones` tanto en `posicionesAux` e `historial` y esa, es la causa del resultado que el OP nos comparte:

```
//misma referencia en memoria por ser un array
let posicionesAux = posiciones;
```

Se puede obtener el resultado deseado, trabajando con una copia del `array` `posiciones`:

```
//creo una copia de posiciones, nueva referencia en memoria
//mantengo el valor de la ultima captura de historial:ver análisis
let posicionesAux = [...posiciones];
```

---

#### Análisis de array y referencias

Aquí, se esta asignando el array `posiciones` a una nueva variable llamada `posicionesAux`:

```
let posicionesAux = posiciones;
```

Luego, se quiere modificar el valor de `posicionesAux`, al operar en cualquiera de las formas:

```
posicionesAux[n][posicion - n] = simbolo;
```

Después, se actualiza el valor de `historial` con la modificación de `posicionesAux`:

```
setHistorial([...historial, posicionesAux]);
```

Pero nótese que `posicionesAux` esta apuntando a la mísma referencia en memoria que `posiciones` y además, `historial` también queda apuntando a dicha referencia.

> misma referencia en memoria: posiciones->posicionesAux->historial

Entonces, al procesar esto en cada evento `cambiarSimbolo`:

```
posicionesAux[n][posicion - n] = simbolo;
```

**Se está modificando la referencia en memoria a la que apuntan `posiciones`, `posicionesAux` e `historial`.**

En consecuencia, cuando se procesa:

```
setHistorial([...historial, posicionesAux]);
```

`historial` tiene la última captura en memoria, del resultado de la operación:

```
posicionesAux[n][posicion - n] = simbolo;
```

Y por lo tanto, el valor de cada elemento del array `historial` tendrá siempre, la última captura de la variable `posiciones`.

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.